# Correct way to type Lists (or anything) in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, typing

How "deep" should one type? F.e:

`List<List<Map<int, List<int>>>>` - looks kind of strange and hard to read, but possible.
Why is it, that I never see typings like this?

I can't find any information about this so I have a feeling that it's wrong or unusual, but it'd be great if someone could elaborate.

Comment: As you saying, its hard to read so if you code like that, even you will be confused after a month to see that snippet of code.And you never see don't mean it not exist. As long as it work, it fine but no one will recommend to code like that

Answer (score 1):

That's logically right to use It, but unreadable for anyone including you. So let's recall the format here:

```
List<
  List<
    Map<int, List<int>>
  >
>
```

The deepest and smallest unit is `Map<int, List<int>>`, It's a bit ugly, but you could still use this. However you need a `List` for this ugly unit, so you should give It a `class` to make It more sense.

```
class Round {
  Map<int, List<int>> monsterIdPerRound; // <round 1, monster 0, 1, 2, 0, 3...>
}
```

And the code could be:

```
List<
  List<Round>
>
```

-

Do you satisfy with this? If not we could make It much more sense as below:

```
// FightManager, arrange the fight with a lot of predefined round of fights.
class FightManager {
  List<Round> rounds;
}
```

Now, the code should be:

```
List<FightManager>
```

-

This is easy to maintain, If you ask what is the `List<FightManager>`? It's still a same way to give It a meaning.

```
class LevelManager {
  List<FightManager> fightManagers;
  LevelManager(this.fightManagers);
}

--

List<FightManager> fightManagers = new List<FightManager>();
// prepare datas...
fightManager.add(getSwordOnlyFightManager());
fightManager.add(getMagicOnlyFightManager());
fightManager.add(getArcherOnlyFightManager());
fightManager.add(getBossFightManager());
fightManager.add(getRandomFightManager());

LevelManager(fightManagers);
```

It's time to go back to the original format, and ask what code do you want to maintain or keep coding?

```
List<
  List<
    Map<int, List<int>>
  >
>
```

or

```
LevelManager
```

Hope you don't mind I made a game example for explaining the code.

Comment: thanks for your elaborate answer! You confirm the feeling I had, that readability (and so maintainability) is the main concern here and that classes are the way to go. I came to this example by asking myself if creating classes "only" for typing is really beneficiary  - assumed they'd never be used again (so without any "work" done inside one of them, like the `fightManager.add(...)` in your example).
Oh and ps: love your game example ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't see typings like this, because it is highly unusual. You can go deeper too if you want to. If you need to define a variable like that, it is highly probable that you are doing something wrong and what you want to achieve can be done in a simpler way.
For the variable you have defined, you'd have to imagine a use case like:
A list of schools in a state(`List<List<Map>>`) having a list of multiple schools(`List<Map>`)(Let say each city has multiple schools) having a map of multiple classes/batches{(A school)(`Map<int, List<int>>`)} of students' role numbers(`List<int>`).
^Read it from bottom to top if you have difficulty imagining.
You'd usually see a table for storing such kind of data structure and not a flat variable. More so, while developing UI for an application.

Comment: @Tokenyet: List<int> is students' role numbers. Map of int with this list can be classes/batches, with each key denoting the class of students for which the list is made. A list of such map can be different schools. And a list of such a list can be  all schools in all cities of a state.